# PostgreSql - extract Month + year from date

Tags: postgresql, date

In a PostgreSQL table I have two columns (int8) containing a Unix timestamp. [Note: this table is not mine, so the columns can be changed to an actual date, hence the conversion in the query.]

below is a stripped down version of my query. What I need to do is to group the entries by month. But in my query below, the entries november 2020 get grouped with the entries of november 2021.

```
select 
DATE_PART('month',to_timestamp(e.startts)) as "Date", sum(e.checked)
from entries e
where 
e.startts >= date_part('epoch', '2020-10-01T15:01:50.859Z'::timestamp)::int8
and e.stopts <  date_part('epoch', '2021-11-08T15:01:50.859Z'::timestamp)::int8
group by "Date"
```

How can I have "Date" as month/year instead of month? so for example 10/20 instead of 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `to_char()` for format the timestamp value:

```
to_char(to_timestamp(e.startts), 'mm/yy') as "Date"
```

Comment: would it also be possible to add a variation? week of year-year.. for example `W30-2021`

Comment: Please see [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIME-TABLE) you probably want `'iw-iyyy'`